# background-image support for HTML Emails with dark mode

Tags: html, css, html-email, mode

This question is in regards to a HTML Email Notification dark or light mode.

I'm having trouble with getting `background-image` to work properly for a css class to display either a white logo or a black logo depending on the mode preferences that the person viewing the email has on their app or OS.

Here's my code...

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: light dark;
  supported-color-schemes: light dark;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .logo {
    background: url(logo-dark.png) center center no-repeat;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .logo {
    background: url(logo-light.png) center center no-repeat;
  }
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  width: 162px;
}
```

I have other css classes in the light and dark media queries that are adjusting colors accordingly. It's really just the background-image property that is giving me trouble.

Has anyone experienced this? Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `url(logo-dark.png)` is a relative URL. What absolute URL do you expect it to resolve to?

Comment: No, the issue is not the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

I have a couple of articles bookmarked for you from the email gurus!

This solution from Remi Parmentier utilises `<picture>` and `<source ... media="(prefers-color-scheme:dark)">` - which is supported on Apple Mail - to swap out an `<img>`. I'm not sure if this was pre- or post- Apple Mail Privacy Protection, which aggressively caches images, but it should work regardless. https://codepen.io/hteumeuleu/pen/porJdjR?editors=1000

The core of it:

```
<div style="margin:auto; text-align:center; width:205px; height:165px;" class="email-picture">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="https://www.hteumeuleu.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/ddg-logo-dark.png" media="(prefers-color-scheme:dark)" />
            <img src="https://www.hteumeuleu.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/ddg-logo-light.png" width="205" height="165" alt="DuckDuckGo" style="vertical-align:middle; max-width:100%; height:auto; font:1em sans-serif; color:#000;" />
        </picture>
    </div>
```

Note also the use of the meta tags, and that might be another reason why yours doesn't work. Be sure to include them.

```
<meta name="color-scheme" value="light dark" />
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark" />
```

This one also includes styles for Outlook.com dark mode:

```
<style id="css-dark-mode-outlook-com">
    [data-ogsb] { color:#fff !important; background-color:#1c1c1c !important; }
    [data-ogsb] .email-picture { background:url('https://www.hteumeuleu.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/ddg-logo-dark.png') no-repeat center; background-size:contain; }
    [data-ogsb] .email-picture img { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
```

The second article explains the use of the html tags picture, source and img, within the context of HTML email: https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/picture

Please note, support for `<picture>` is limited, however, so is support for @media prefers-color-scheme. Check https://www.caniemail.com/ for details.

You might also consider giving your fallback/normal logo a white (or your background colour) stroke or soft 'outer glow' (with transparency) so that it can be seen on those email clients that automate - but do not let you control - dark mode colour changes. See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/ for more details and general background to everything dark mode.

Comment: Thanks for this Nathan, I actually went with a solution that uses an `img` with a `class` and I'm using the `filter` properties to change the logo from black to white. I'll post the solution shortly. Still doing some testing.

Comment: i guess thats fine if you know you'll only have recipient using apple mail, unfortunately the popular gmail email client doesn't support this (it strips out 'srcset=' . I wonder if the only way to achieve this is using "Dark Mode media query" to target Apple, Gmail, Outlook at once, swaping the img out by hiding one and showing the other, We really need a good how to approach that works with most major email clients.  
p.S. it almost sounds like you wrote the posted litmus article, which is quiet good one. =) FYI https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-srcset/

Comment: Yes @Markus for Gmail and those that don't support being able to select for dark mode, you have to have an image that works in both dark and light mode. Jpgs won't get changed, but transparent pngs may need a small stroke around it to be seen (for one example). So that will cover you across everything. Thanks for the compliment but no I didn't write the article :)